Win10 pip installation failed
When I type "pip install ..." in cmd, it return an error like:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021FC8D246E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Unable to connect because the target computer actively refused it.'))': /simple/pygame/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame

My operating system is Windows10. I've tried turning off the proxy, updating pip, and connecting to vpn, but to no avail.

Please post your full code and full traceback error.

py -m pip install ...

Are you currently using a proxy? You can double check proxy settings and re-disable it using:
setx HTTP_PROXY ""
setx HTTPS_PROXY ""

Or you can disable the proxy altogether in the pip config. Check for the existence of the 'pip.ini' file in your user directory path, create one if it is not there, and if it is already add this to it:
[global]
proxy =

If you have already updated pygame and/or used a VPN and its still not working, you might have to download the pygame package manually:
pip install path\to\pygame.whl

I had a similar issue when working in VSCode, and when I installed it manually it ended up working. Hope this helps! Feel free to reach out!!
